# Cannot uninstall System Center Virtual Machine Mananger (SCVMM)

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, scvmm

I wanted to install the new SCVMM 2008 R2 RC, so I thought I would uninstall SCVMM 2008 to do a clean install.

When I try to uninstall it I get the following message:

*[Window Title]*
Microsoft® System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008

*[Main Instruction]*
Microsoft® System Center Virtual Machine Manager 2008 has stopped working

*[Content]*
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

*[Close program]*

After which the uninstaller closes and I can't remove the program. (I have tried it with the Local Admin, and 2 different domain users. (one that installed the software and 1 that was used (on the first install) as the login used for the Agent.)) I have also tried it with both Retaining and removing data.

I also tried turning off the VMM Service to see if that would help (it does not)

In short, I am stuck with this program until I format the drive. (Booo!)

I thought I would try to upgrade instead of doing a fresh install, but that fails as well. It says it can't connect to the SQL DB.  That does not surprise me because it is not there (I am guessing the partial uninstall caused it to be removed.)

I may have to format and try again, but I thought I would ask around first.

[LATER NOTE: I thought I would try to do a repair on the original install, but when I ran the installer again (from the disk) it just started up the Uninstaller instead.  (The uninstaller failed as indicated above.)]

Comment: Vaccano-

It looks like ServerFault does not have private messaging yet, but could you zip up the contents of %systemdrive%\programdata\vmmlogs and send them to my firstname dot lastname at microsoft dot come and I'll see if I can get one of the SCVMM folks to take a look.

Comment: dangit... come = com in my e-mail address.

Comment: Looking forward to hearing more, as this update is on my list for next week.  ;)

Comment: One other thing that may be of note (I did not include it in my post) is that I could not add a host to my install of SCVMM.  It kept giving me an error.  I had no problems on the same computer 2 days ago when I was using Windows Server 2008.  I decided then that I wanted to try it with Windows Server 2008 R2.  So I reformatted my drive and started over with a fresh Windows Server 2008 R2 install.  I followed the same steps as I did with my Windows Server 2008 install but I was not able to get a host to add.  That is when I thought of going to the R2 of SCVMM.  (the rest is in the Post above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have found out for those that come after.

This error was due to doing the following:

- Installing Windows Server 2008
- Upgrading to Windows Server 2008 R2
- Installing SCVMM
- Trying to Uninstall SCVMM

Sean Earp worked as an intermediary between me and the developers of SCVMM (thanks Sean).  They told me that the upgrading of Windows Server 2008 to Windows Server 2008 R2 and then using SCVMM is not supported.  (I imagine it will be supported with SCVMM R2).  They said there is a way to manually undo the problem, but that it was fairly intensive.  I opted to just wipe the drive.